# Code not creating new excel sheet in output excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading in multiple excel files (file1_.xlsx, file2_.xlsx, etc) that contain multiple sheets of data, combining everything and then printing it to a new excel file called output. Also in output are sheets containing multiple tables of summary data for each file. So, for example, the output file should have sheets: final, file1sum, file2sum, etc. And file1sum will contain tables sumtable1,sumtable2,etc, file2sum will also contain sumtable1, sumtable2, etc but for file 2. Hope that makes sense

```
 for f in files:
     name=f.split("_")[0]
     xls=pd.ExcelFile(f)
     sheets=xls.sheet_names

     for i in range(len(sheets))
         create final table (dataframe)
         create sumtable1 (dataframe)
         create sumtable2 (dataframe)
         create sumtable3 (dataframe)

     writer=pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")
     if not os.path.exist("output.xlsx"):
         print final table to sheet final in output
     else: 
         df=pd.read_excel("output.xlsx")
         merge df and final table 
         print df to output

     listOfSumTables=[sumtable1,sumtable2,sumtable3]
     row=0
     for dataframe in listOfSumTables:
         if not dataframe.empty:
              writeDF(dataframe,name,row,writer)
              row=row+len(dataframe)+2
     writer.save()
```

where writeDF is the following function

```
def writeDF(df,name,row,writer):
     if name=='file1':
       df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='file1sum', index=False, 
       startrow=row, startcol=0)
     elif name=='file2':
       df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='file2sum', index=False, 
       startrow=row, startcol=0)
```

The problem is in the output file I am getting sheets final and file2sum only when I should be getting final, file1sum and file2sum. final and file2sum look how they are supposed to, it is just not making all the sheets for some reason. It is creating the tables for each file correctly, triggering the writeDF function correctly. I think it has to do with where I am opening and saving the writer but I tried moving it around and it doesn't make all three sheets.

Comment: Looks like your first if condition is being skipped, meaning `name=='file1'` is always `False`. I would suggest you look into `name` variable. I also do not see a need for a `writeDF` function, you can just concatenate `name` and `'sum'` in your `df.to_excel(..,sheet_name=name+'sum', ..)` without needing another function `writeDF`. Just my thoughts, you might have other reasons for this.

Comment: That's the thing, it is not being skipped. I checked by including print statements in it and it seems to be triggering but either not making the sheet or saving over the sheet? Can't tell

Comment: FYI to readers: I had to add these two lines of code     book=load_workbook(p+"\output.xlsx")
writer.book = book for the condition if the path exists in order to make the new sheets